# Is the partial derivative of a sum always the sum of partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

What I mean is, if we want to find the partial deriative

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} (f(x,y)+g(x,y))$

Then is it always true that:

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} (f(x,y)+g(x,y))=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} f(x,y) + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} g(x,y)$

and more over can this be extended to any finite sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is true (assuming that the RHS exists and you don't have indeterminate form). However, the LHS might exist even though RHS does not exist or it is indeterminate.

Comment: I shall add that this is a linear operator: not only can we break this apart by plus and minus signs, but we may also push and pull scalars out of differentiation operators.